# How to check for correlations using ANOVA between the selected feature columns and the target feature column

Tags: python, classification, pandas, anova

*Suppose I have a set of feature columns that I select to check for correlations with the target feature 'is_Star'; which is of binary values and the former consists of numeric values*

*Why do i end up getting an array of NAN values? Also, I have accounted for missing values, if any.*

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import f_classif

X = star_data.drop(['class', 'is_Star'], axis=1)

y = star_data['is_Star']

anova = f_classif(X, y)

anova
```

**The output given is as below**

```
(array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]),

 array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]))
```